# React - Flatlist doesn't render anything

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a React-Native project that renders a list of items.

I was using .map function to do it but since I'll have several items in the future, I'm trying to migrate the function to [flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html).

The documentation provided by React is quite simple, yet I can't get it to work. Any ideas why?

here's my code:

```
renderEtiquetas() {

        // this commented code works just fine
        // return this.props.etiquetas.map(etiqueta =>
        //   <EtiquetaDetail key={etiqueta.id} etiqueta={etiqueta} galleries={ this.props.galleries } />
        // );

        <FlatList
          data={ this.props.etiquetas }
          keyExtractor={etiqueta => etiqueta.id}
          renderItem={({ etiqueta }) => (
            <EtiquetaDetail key={etiqueta.id} etiqueta={etiqueta} galleries={ this.props.galleries } />
          )}
        />

  }
```

here is the content for this.props.etiquetas has this format: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
and here is one of the objects in it:
{id: 523, date: "2014-04-16T16:30:03", date_gmt: "2014-04-16T16:30:03", modified: "2018-01-13T00:00:43"}

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was missing the return word before https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html
Also, I tried extraData={this.state} but didn't do anything.

Thanks @Chao Chen for answering!

Comment: extraData only re-renders that component if the data you are passing is changed.

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience. Flatlist will consume your data to renderItem.

change your flatlist  tag to

```
    <FlatList
      data={ this.props.etiquetas }
      keyExtractor={etiqueta => etiqueta.id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <EtiquetaDetail key={item.id} etiqueta={item} galleries={ this.props.galleries } />
      )}
    />
```

If you want Flatlist re-render properly. Add extraData={this.state} to it.

Answer (score 1):

Using FlatList is a wise move because it has better performance gains

I faced the same problem and I solved it by using `return (<MyComponent />)`

in the `renderItem` function

because writing your component without return won't work, here is a little example

```
            <FlatList 
            data={citiesLabelsAndNumbers.map(x=>x.city)}
            renderItem={({item}) => {
                return (<HorizontalCard text={item} onPress={()=>{}} />)
            }}
            keyExtractor={(item,index) => String(index)}
            />
```